# AttributeError: 'FactorAnalyzer' object has no attribute 'analyze'

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to implement factor analysis using python 3.7. I'm using following code

```
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
df=pd.read_csv('bfi.csv')
fa = FactorAnalyzer()
fa.analyze(df, 25, rotation=None)
```

I have installed package `factor_analyzer` today only. But I'm getting error message 
`AttributeError: 'FactorAnalyzer' object has no attribute 'analyze'`
Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Firstly in your code you're trying to call `.analyze` on `fa` but you only defined `a` (but I'm assuming that's a typo... If you use `dir` it will show you all the attributes an object has. Alternatively, you can read the documentation for the package

Comment: You can try installing an earlier version of factor_analyzer (try 0.2.3)

Answer (score 11):

FactorAnalyzer module does not show any attribute analyze

That's the reason why it throws AttributeError.

Instead, you may get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors by using `fa.fit` if you have instantiated FactorAnalyzer as 'fa'

Try using this,

```py
fa = FactorAnalyzer()
fa.fit(df)
eigen_values, vectors = fa.get_eigenvalues()
```

Plot the eigen_values against the column features which will give you information about the n_features

Then use the `set_params` attribute to set the value of n_features

```py
fa = FactorAnalyzer()
fa.set_params(n_factors='blahblahblah!', rotation='refer the docs')
fa.fit(df)
loadings = fa.loadings_
```

This probably will help you!

Good day

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Okay, Sure I will do

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here.

`a = FactorAnalyzer()`

either change it to `fa = FactorAnalyzer()`

otherwise Change this line
`fa.analyze(df, 25, rotation=None)` to
`a.analyze(df, 25, rotation=None)`

Also, you may get another error, as `df` not defined. You need to define the pandas dataframe `df` before invoking.

## Update:

I looked into the list of modules available in the FactorAnalyzer. There is no such module available. Assuming following is the content of bfi.csv file `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vincentarelbundock/Rdatasets/master/csv/psych/bfi.csv`

```
C:\Users\kuvivek\Desktop>python
ActivePython 3.6.6 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.6.6 (default, Nov  7 2019, 20:16:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\kuvivek\Desktop\bfi.csv')
>>> fa = FactorAnalyzer()
>>> dir(fa)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_fit_factor_analysis', '_fit_ml_objective', '_fit_principal', '_fit_uls_objective', '_get_factor_variance', '_get_param_names', '_normalize_ml', '_normalize_uls', 'bounds', 'corr_', 'fit', 'fit_transform', 'get_communalities', 'get_eigenvalues', 'get_factor_variance', 'get_params', 'get_uniquenesses', 'impute', 'is_corr_matrix', 'loadings_', 'mean_', 'method', 'n_factors', 'phi_', 'rotation', 'rotation_kwargs', 'rotation_matrix_', 'set_params', 'std_', 'structure_', 'transform', 'use_smc']
```

You need to use any one of these, as there is no such function `analyze` available in the FactoryAnalyzer Class. In order to get complete documentation, use the following command as shown below.

```
>>>
>>> help(fa)
Help on FactorAnalyzer in module factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer object:

class FactorAnalyzer(sklearn.base.BaseEstimator, sklearn.base.TransformerMixin)
 |  A FactorAnalyzer class, which -
 |      (1) Fits a factor analysis model using minres, maximum likelihood,
 |          or principal factor extraction and returns the loading matrix
 |      (2) Optionally performs a rotation, with method including:
 |
 |          (a) varimax (orthogonal rotation)
 |          (b) promax (oblique rotation)
 |          (c) oblimin (oblique rotation)
 |          (d) oblimax (orthogonal rotation)
 |          (e) quartimin (oblique rotation)
 |          (f) quartimax (orthogonal rotation)
 |          (g) equamax (orthogonal rotation)
 |
 |  Parameters
 |  ----------
 |  n_factors : int, optional
 |      The number of factors to select.
 |      Defaults to 3.
 |  rotation : str, optional
 |      The type of rotation to perform after
 |      fitting the factor analysis model.
 |      If set to None, no rotation will be performed,
 |      nor will any associated Kaiser normalization.
 |
 |      Methods include:
 |
-- More  --
```

Comment: I think it's just a typo in the post.  The error would have been a`NameError` otherwise.

Comment: Sorry kvivek, it was a typo & df was also defined, I just put few lines of code. Corrected it

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, fa.analyze doesn't work.
Try:

```
fa = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=6,rotation='varimax')
fa.fit(dataset)
```

Then create a dataframe:

```
factor_df=pd.DataFrame(fa.loadings_,index=dataframe.columns))
print(factor_df)
```

I found great help from [this link:](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/dimensionality-reduction-using-factor-analysis-in-python/)